# Visual Studio 2015 find and replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I have to replace many membervariables in VisualStudio from:

```
 _MyVariable
```

to

```
_myVariable
```

The name is absolutly variable for sure. Iam using this to find my "wrong" named variables:

```
(_)([A-Z])((.)*)
```

But i have no idea how to replace this. Need the same name as before, just the first capital letter needs to be changed into small letter.

Someone has an idea?

UPDATE:

From other entries i found out that $x give me access to sections of the found word. So i would need something like $1$2$3 and $2 needs to be small letter.

Comment: You cannot do that with Visual Studio F&R regex. You can do it in Notepad++ with `(?<=\b_)[A-Z]` to replace with `\L$0\E` with *Match Case* turned ON (e.g. `_MyVariable _MyNew_Variable` -> `_myVariable _myNew_Variable`). You can do it in SublimeText, too. I will post it as a workaround answer, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with Visual Studio Find&Replace regex because .NET regex does not support `\L`/`\U` - `\E` case changing operators.

You can do it in Notepad++ with `(?<=\b_)[A-Z]` to replace with `\L$0\E` (make sure *Match Case* is turned ON). E.g. `_MyVariable _MyNew_Variable` will become `_myVariable _myNew_Variable`:

[image]

You can do it in SublimeText, too:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press **ctrl + "H"**. It will bring the find and replace menu. There you can write which name you want to change. You can select "replace all" and it will do for all the found instances.

Comment: yes this would be the way if i want replace one variable used x times. But i need to replace x variables with different names. Sorry that my Question wasnt clear to you. _MyVariable is just an example. Think about there are 50 variables with different name but all starts _X and now need _x

Comment: Oh.. sorry. I misunderstood the question